# Can I use JavaScript Libraries like JQuery and BootStrap within my React Native App

Tags: reactive-programming, react-native, react-native-ios

Can I use JavaScript Libraries(jQuery, BootStrap) inside my React Native App?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by itself is not supported in React Native as it uses different styling options for example 'font-size' css property in React Native is written as fontSize. All dashed ones are changed to camelcase. React Native is **native**, it isn't a **web view** or wrapped in an app container, so CSS as CSS itself cannot be applied there.

you can use libraries like [native base](https://nativebase.io/) and [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap` by itself is not supported in the `react-native` but you can use many alternative ui kits in `react-native`. You can use [RN Material Kit](http://xinthink.github.io/react-native-material-kit/) for implementing UI in `react-native` which is more similar to bootstrap. 
For `jQuery` also same because its heavily relies on the web dom manipulation.